# Numbering every number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to put number every number using jquery or javascript:

If i input this number:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10 and so on
```

then my expected output is:

```
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1, 8.2, 9.3, 10.1 and so on
```

Comment: What should be the output if the i/p is `1,1,2,3,1,5,6,5,2,1`?? As in your example problem, you have repeated numbers but they are all clustered together in a sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10];
var newArr = [arr[0] + ".1"];
var n = 1;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
        n++;
    }
    else {
        n = 1;
    }
    newArr.push(arr[i] + "." + n);
}
console.info(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sky Fang, but not working take a look with my jsdiddle, I copied your code. please help: http://jsfiddle.net/ehillanichole/woykv768/

Comment: `var arr = $('#input').val().split(',');` You need to split first,thx

Comment: Thanks @Sky Fang, now it worked now :) sorry by the way im a newbie of jquery.

Comment: It is no matter, everyone is a newbie when it start to learn something,just like now I am still poor in English :)

Answer (score 0):

This does want you want:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10];
var newarr = []; check = 0; count = 0;
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
if(check != arr[i]){ count = 1; check = arr[i]; } else { count++; }
newarr.push(check+'.'+count);
}
console.log(newarr);
```

Ofcourse the numbers should be grouped together, else you will get 1.1,1.2,2.1,3.1,1.1,1.2,5.1 Then you should first do arr.sort()